# Can't get RS-232 Commands to work sending from arduino

Tags: c, arduino, serial-port, embedded, serial-communication

Having issues sending RS-232 Commands from Arduino Mega to ENTTEC DMXStreamer. The RS-232 API is located here [enter link description here](https://dol2kh495zr52.cloudfront.net/pdf/misc/rs232_spec.pdf). I am trying to send 3 commands H1 (Stop Show) HA (Load Show in slot A) H0 (Start Show that is loaded). I have tried multiple things to send the data.

```
setup(){
    Serial2.begin(9600); //default baud rate of DMXStreamer
    Serial.begin(115200);
}
loop(){
    Serial2.print("H1HAH0");
    delay(3000);
}
```

I also tried

```
Serial2.write(0x48);
Serial2.write(0x31);
Serial2.write(0x48);
Serial2.write(0x41);
Serial2.write(0x48);
Serial2.write(0x30);
```

All I get in return from the DMXStreamer is '''. I don't even see those characters as possible response codes in the API. A successful send is supposed to return '!' and negative response is '?'.

This is the code I used to read the response.

```
String Message = "";
while(Serial2.available())
{
    char inChar = Serial2.read();
    Message += inChar;
}
Serial.println(Message);
```

I then hooked up a usb to serial converter to the DMXStreamer and used Realterm to send the data. I went to the send tab in Realterm and typed "H1HAH0" in the box and pressed the Send ASCII button. The Streamer returned positive response !!! and I got the desired result the DMX show in slot A started playing.

What am I doing wrong in sending the data. As a side note I at one point want to use the command H3101 instead of H0. The notes for the command from the API are below. I am not sure how to sent the 101 part of the command based on the notes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**From the API**
H Command
This command is used to start,stop a show and set the show to run.

- H0 Command, Start Show Format H0

If no show is stored this will have no effect

- H1 Command, Stop Show The command will stop the show.

Format H1

- H3 Command, Start Show with loop times

Format H3x
Warning the X value is 8 bit BINARY data, not ascii.
This command will start the show and loop X times.
To run the show once X must be set to 0x00 the maximum number of loops is 100. If X is set to 101
the show will loop forever.

Comment: How have you connected this RS232 device to the Arduino?  You do know that a remotely modern Arduino does not speak RS232 and will be **damaged by RS232 voltage levels**, right?  Even in the old, old days, I'm pretty sure that the models that had an RS232 port instead of USB only had one such port.

Comment: I was not aware. This is probably why it doesnt work. I am connect directly from the RS-232 device to my Serial port pins for Serial2. So I need some type of shield then. Thanks for your comment it is going to save me alot of frustration trying to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Yes, you need an inverting RS232 level shifter, perhaps something with a MAX232 or any of its many descendants or alternatives.  Hopefully your Arduino survived, but be aware of the possibility that those particular pins are damaged.

Comment: One quick question if the problem is level of the signals then why did it work when I used my usb to serial converter? Do those usually have a level shifter built into them that will work with low voltage (5v) as well RS-232 level signals? Because I was able to communicate with my 5v Arduino with the same USB to serial converter.

Comment: Until you document *exactly* what you have, it's impossible to say.  That goes for both the cable and the DMX device.  You need to post actual *engineering* specs.

Answer (score 0):

The bytes are commming slow on 9600 baud. You will see `available()` 0 between them and before they arrive. Use `Serial2.readString()` for test. It waits for next byte until a second.

```
String Message = Serial2.readString();
Serial.println(Message);
```

Note: this is for a test. Don't use String or readString in the final sketch. Use C strings and readBytes with length or terminator specified.